# Reverse for 'ptrips' with arguments '('', '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['details/trips/(?P<trip_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<passenger_id>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, django

This is a train tickets booking system, im trying to pass 2 id(trip_id/passenger_id) at the same url path so the django can remember the number of passengers and then create a number of tickets forms based on the number of passenger by id

## urls.py

```py
    path('trips/<int:trip_id>/',views.ticket_booking, name='trips'),
    path('trips/<int:trip_id>/<int:passenger_id>/',views.passengers_page, name='ptrips'),
    path('review/<int:ticket_id>/',views.review_page, name='rtickets'),
    re_path(r'^from/(?P<start_station>[0-9]{1,50})/$', views.details_page, name='details_page'),
    path('', views.details_page, name='booking'),
```

## views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from .models import Ticket, Trip, Passenger
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def ticket_booking(request, trip_id, passenger_id):
    trip = get_object_or_404( Trip, pk=trip_id)
    passengers = list(Passenger.objects.filter(pk=passenger_id))
    error = None
    ticket = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name')
        middle_name = request.POST.get('middle_name')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        ticket = Ticket(trip=trip,first_name=first_name, middle_name=middle_name,
            last_name=last_name, email=email,gender=gender)
        try:
            ticket.full_clean()
            ticket.save()
            return redirect('tickets',ticket_id=ticket.id)
        except ValidationError as e:
            error = dict(e)
            print(e)
    context = { 'trip': trip,'error':error, 'ticket':ticket, 'passengers':passengers }
    return render(request, 'details/ticket.html', context)
```

## html

```py
<div class="container marketing">
    {% for trip in trips %}
    <div class="card text-center ">
      <div class="card-header">
        Ride Details
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Start</h4>
        <h5 value="{{trip.id}}">{{trip.start_station}}</h5>
        <h4>End</h4>
        <h5 value="{{trip.id}}">{{trip.end_station}}</h5>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'ptrips' trip_id passenger.id %}" role="button">Book Now</a> 
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

Comment: It should be `trip.id` as for passenger, you have passed a collection of `Passengers`, so you can not just pass that, you will need to pick a passenger, and then pass `passenger.id`.

Comment: To add to Willem’s comment, you have a single passenger id so using filter and list doesn’t make sense. Do `passenger = get_object_or_404(Passenger, pk=passenger_id)`.

Comment: You haven't shown us how `passenger` is assigned in the template.  If it's in a `{% for passenger in passengers %}` loop, please show that.